# Trouble running nested jobs in quartz

Tags: java, spring, quartz-scheduler, jobs, job-scheduling

I'm using Quartz 1.8 to write some code that runs a job on a daily/weekly/monthly basis. When that job runs it should create a nested job. For some reason though, neither the nested JobDetail nor Trigger wind up with entries in the database, nor do they run.

Here's the example I'm working with:

```
public class QuartzSSCCE {
    private static Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(QuartzSSCCE.class);
    private static long counter = 0L;
    private static Scheduler scheduler;

    public void scheduleOuterJob(){
        try{
            LOG.info("About to try to schedule OuterJob");
            CronTrigger ct = new CronTrigger("OuterJobTrigger" + counter++, "OuterJobGroup", "30 * * ? * *");
            ct.setStartTime((new DateTime(new Date())).plusSeconds(3).toDate());
            DateTime endTime = new DateTime(new Date());
            endTime = endTime.plusMinutes(5);
            ct.setEndTime(endTime.toDate());

            JobDetail jd = new JobDetail("OuterJobDetail" + counter++, "OuterJobGroup", OuterJob.class);

            scheduler.scheduleJob(jd, ct);
        } catch (Exception e){
            LOG.fatal("something went wrong while scheduling the outer job", e);
        }
    }

    public static class OuterJob implements Job {
        @Override
        public void execute(JobExecutionContext context) throws JobExecutionException {
            try{
                LOG.info("running OuterJob");
                //Trigger trigger = TriggerUtils.makeImmediateTrigger("InnerTriggerName" + counter++, 1, 1);
                SimpleTrigger simpleTrigger = new SimpleTrigger(
                        "InnerTriggerName" + counter++,
                        "InnerTriggerGroup",
                        (new DateTime(new Date())).plusSeconds(10).toDate(),
                        (new DateTime(new Date()).plusSeconds(50)).toDate(),
                        1,
                        1000
                );
                JobDetail jd = new JobDetail("InnerJobDetail" + counter++, "InnerJobGroup", InnerJob.class);
                scheduler.scheduleJob(jd, simpleTrigger);
            } catch (Exception e){
                LOG.fatal("something went wrong while scheduling the inner job", e);
            }
        }
    }

    public static class InnerJob implements Job {
        @Override
        public void execute(JobExecutionContext context) throws JobExecutionException {
            LOG.info("InnerJob is running. The time at the beep is: " + new Date());
        }
    }

    public void setScheduler(Scheduler scheduler) {
        QuartzSSCCE.scheduler = scheduler;
    }
}
```

This class obtains an `Scheduler` instance from a `SchedulerFactoryBean`. Elsewhere in my code I instantiate an instance of `QuartzSSCCE` like so:

```
QuartzSSCCE quartzSSCCE = new QuartzSSCCE();
quartzSSCCE.scheduleOuterJob();
```

I wind up seeing entries in the log for "About to try to schedule OuterJob" and "running OuterJob" but it appears that the InnerJob never gets run. I've attempted this with both a trigger returned from the call to `TriggerUtils.makeImmediateTrigger()` as well as a `SimpleTrigger`.

Why won't my InnerJob run?

Answer (score 2):

First of all, my English is poor!

Quartz use reflection to create job instance, as your code show:

```
JobDetail jd = new JobDetail("InnerJobDetail" + counter++, "InnerJobGroup", InnerJob.class);
```

But nested class can't create instance directly by reflection, so the InnerJob is not fired.